# Trying to add a dialog when tap a long click on list item, cause StackOverflow Error

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog

I want to add a Dialog with 2 buttons *edit* and *remove*(only remove implemented actually) when I use longClick (the standard click opens the item details)

so I have tried to follow the guide on [this link](http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/07/30/android-long-click-context-menu/)

and I have added

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_dialog, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.remove_item:

        final String[] listItem = getItemId();

        String idItemSel = listItem[info.position];

        delItem(idItemSel);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

(where *adapter* is my list adapter)

and I have configured the listener in this way

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                .....

            }
        });


        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                view.showContextMenu();
                return true;

            }
        });
```

All works fine but when I use long click the app crash with this error (on invocation of `view.showContextMenu();`) :

```
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780): java.lang.StackOverflowError
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:1995)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onItemLongClick(MyItems.java:615)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2001)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2520)
08-02 18:13:12.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at detailer.myapp.it.MyItems$6.onIt
```

Any solution to the problem or alternatives to view a simple context dialog when I long press a list item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have registered your ListView for a ContextMenu *and* set an OnItemLongClickListener that calls showContextMenu(), this creates a circular logic:

- The OnItemLongClickListener calls the ContextMenu,
- The ContextMenu calls the OnItemLongClickListener,
- The OnItemLongClickListener calls the ContextMenu,
- The ContextMenu calls the OnItemLongClickListener,
- etc. until the stack overflow occurs

To fix this:

First, remove the OnItemLongClickListener since it is redundant with a ContextMenu.

Second, double check how you are using your ContextMenu. You have the menu saved in the layout folder and you don't need to invoke showContextMenu() if you have already used registerForContextMenu().

---

To setup a ContextMenu, simply pass the whole ListView to registerForContextMenu():

```
registerForContextMenu(list);
```

You'll need an XML like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:title="@string/edit" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:title="@string/remove" />
</menu>
```

Save this in a new folder `res/menu`, I named it context_menu.xml.

Then change your method to create the ContextMenu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

Now each row will automatically open a ContextMenu when long clicked.

---

If you need help with editing and deleting row, post the code that you use to create the ListView and Adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have used similar code except for the menu in another folder... however also if I try your solution get the same error.

Comment: Did you remove the OnItemLongClickListener?

Comment: I updated my answer to make that more clear, if anyone else has a similar problem reads this. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

if you click Textview(autolink) in Listview and then crash remove this   android:textIsSelectable="true" in my case it solved .I have the same error